# The problem of asynchronous device communication with modbus

Tags: c#, modbus

First of all, I'm gonna mention that I'm trying to do. I get a lot of data transiently from different places. Via SQL connection,ı save data to the database automatically and transfer data to UI.
This is my method:

```
    private void Read(object val)
    {
        Manager mngr = new Manager();
        List<tbl_Devices> devices = mngr.Devices.GetList();
        while (true)
        {

                Parallel.For(0, devices.Count, i =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IModbusMaster master = null;
                        int tempi = i;
                        Manager _manager = new Manager();
                        int deviceID = devices[tempi].ID;
                        tbl_Devices device = devices[tempi];

                        List<tbl_DeviceTemplates> templaIDs = _manager.DeviceTemplates.Where(x => x.DeviceID == deviceID).ToList();
                        List<DeviceDatas> deviceDatas = new List<DeviceDatas>();
                        List<tbl_TagTemplateValues> registerList = null;
                        List<tbl_TagTemplateValues> tagList = _manager.TagTemplateValues.GetList();
                        for (int t = 0; t < templaIDs.Count; t++)
                        {
                            ushort startAddress = 0;
                            ushort numInputs = 1;
                            int min = 0, max = 0;
                            int numberOfPoints = 0;
                            int loopT = t;
                            try
                            {

                                int templateID = templaIDs[loopT].TemplateID;
                                registerList = new List<tbl_TagTemplateValues>();
                                registerList = tagList.Where(x => x.TagTemplateID == templateID).ToList();

                                try
                                {
                                    min = registerList.OrderBy(x => x.Adress.toInt32()).First().Adress.toInt32();
                                    if (min >= 1) //4IBB
                                    {
                                        min = registerList.OrderBy(x => x.Adress.toInt32()).First().Adress.toInt32() - 1;
                                    }
                                    max = registerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Adress.toInt32()).First().Adress.toInt32() + 1;
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    min = registerList.OrderBy(x => x.Adress).First().Adress.Split('.')[0].toInt32();
                                    if (min >= 1) //4IBB
                                    {
                                        min = registerList.OrderBy(x => x.Adress).First().Adress.Split('.')[0].toInt32() - 1;
                                    }
                                    max = registerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Adress).First().Adress.Split('.')[0].toInt32() + 1;
                                }
                                int LastVariableID = registerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Adress).First().VariableID;
                                numberOfPoints = max - min;
                                if (LastVariableID == 11 || LastVariableID == 12)
                                {
                                    numberOfPoints++;
                                }

                                startAddress = ushort.Parse(min.ToString());
                                numInputs = ushort.Parse(numberOfPoints.ToString());


                                ModbusDeviceInfo modbusDeviceInfo = new ModbusDeviceInfo()
                                {
                                    ID = device.ID,
                                    CreateDate = device.CreateDate,
                                    CreatedUserID = device.CreatedUserID,
                                    DeviceName = device.DeviceName,
                                    IpAdress = device.IpAdress,
                                    Port = device.Port,
                                    SlaveAdress = device.SlaveAdress,
                                    Status = device.Status
                                };
                                Random rnd = new Random();
                                master = new ModbusTCPMaster(device.IpAdress, (short)device.Port, 5000);
                                master.Disconnection();
                                master.Connection();
                                byte[] plcData = master.ReadHoldingRegisters((byte)device.SlaveAdress, min.ToString(), (ushort)numberOfPoints);
                                short[] result = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Int.ToArray(plcData);
                                deviceDatas.Add(new DeviceDatas { DeviceID = device.ID, Min = min, TemplateID = templateID, NumberOfPoints = numberOfPoints, RegisterList = registerList, Datas = result });
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                        }
                        DeviceReaded(device.ID, deviceDatas);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                });

                Console.WriteLine("READ OK");

        }
    }



    private void DeviceReaded(int deviceID, List<DeviceDatas> deviceDatas)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < deviceDatas.Count; d++)
        {

            int loopd = d;
            List<TagAdressValues> tagAdressValues = new List<TagAdressValues>();

            int[] dataArray = new int[deviceDatas[loopd].Datas.Length];
            for (int a = 0; a < dataArray.Length; a++)
            {
                int loopa = a;
                dataArray[a] = deviceDatas[loopd].Datas[loopa];
            }

            AsyncRead(deviceDatas[loopd].TemplateID, deviceDatas[loopd].Min, deviceDatas[loopd].NumberOfPoints, dataArray, deviceDatas[loopd].RegisterList, tagAdressValues, deviceID);

        }
    }


    private void AsyncRead(int templateID, int min, int numberOfPoints, int[] plcData, List<tbl_TagTemplateValues> rList, List<TagAdressValues> tagAdressValues, int deviceID)
    {
        try
        {
            tagAdressValues = new List<TagAdressValues>();
            List<tbl_TagTemplateValues> registerList = rList;

            List<TagTemplateArchive> templateArchives = new List<TagTemplateArchive>();
            Manager _manager = new Manager();


            int startAdress = min.toInt32();
            try
            {
                for (int iplc = 0; iplc < numberOfPoints; iplc++)
                {
                    int Loopiplc = iplc;
                    TagAdressValues tval = new TagAdressValues();
                    tval.Adress = startAdress.ToString();
                    tval.Index = Loopiplc;
                    tval.Value = plcData[Loopiplc].ToString();
                    tagAdressValues.Add(tval);
                    startAdress++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("for array------------->");
            }

            registerList = registerList.OrderBy(x => x.VariableID).ToList();

            for (int r = 0; r < registerList.ToList().Count(); r++)
            {

                try
                {
                    int loopr = r;
                    var register = registerList[loopr];
                    double value = 0;

                    TagAdressValues tagValue = tagAdressValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Adress == registerList[loopr].Adress);
                    bool IsTagValue = tagAdressValues.Any(x => x.Adress == registerList[loopr].Adress);

                    if (!IsTagValue)
                    {
                        string adress = registerList[loopr].Adress.Split('.')[0];
                        tagValue = tagAdressValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Adress == adress);
                        value = tagValue.Value.toDouble();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = tagValue.Value.toDouble();
                    }

                    if (register.VariableID == 1 || register.VariableID == 2)
                    {
                        value = tagValue.Value.toDouble();
                        if (value > 32767 && register.VariableID == 1)
                        {
                            value = value - 65536;
                        }

                    }//INT-UINT

                    else if (register.VariableID == 3)
                    {
                        List<DigitalVariables> _tagValueAdresses = new List<DigitalVariables>();
                        for (int iAdress = 0; iAdress < registerList.Count; iAdress++)
                        {
                            int LoopiAdress = iAdress;
                            string adress = registerList[LoopiAdress].Adress.Split('.')[0];
                            if (!_tagValueAdresses.Any(x => x.Adress == adress))
                            {
                                _tagValueAdresses.Add(new DigitalVariables { Adress = adress });
                            }
                        }
                        string splitAdress = registerList[loopr].Adress.Split('.')[0];
                        int index = _tagValueAdresses.FindIndex(x => x.Adress == splitAdress);
                        value = tagAdressValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Adress == splitAdress).Value.toDouble();
                        string ModBusStr = register.Adress.ToString();
                        string ModBusID;

                        if (ModBusStr.IndexOf('.') != -1)
                        {
                            string[] ModBusArray = ModBusStr.Split('.');
                            ModBusID = ModBusArray[0].ToString();
                            bitNumber = Convert.ToInt32(ModBusArray[1].ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModBusID = value.ToString();
                        }
                        if (ModBusStr.IndexOf('.') != -1)
                        {
                            BitArray b = new BitArray(new int[] { value.toInt32() });
                            if (b[bitNumber])
                            {
                                value = 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                value = 0;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            value = value.toDouble();
                        }

                    }//DIGITAL 4x 

                    else if (register.VariableID == 4) //LONG
                    {
                        byte[] firstArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value.toInt32());
                        var value2 = plcData[tagValue.Index + 1].toInt32();
                        byte[] lastArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value2);

                        var firstValue = string.Empty;
                        var lastValue = string.Empty;

                        if (register.VariableID == 4)//LONG INVERSE
                        {
                            firstValue = ByteToStr(lastArr[1]) + ByteToStr(lastArr[0]);
                            lastValue = ByteToStr(firstArr[1]) + ByteToStr(firstArr[0]);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            firstValue = ByteToStr(firstArr[1]) + ByteToStr(firstArr[0]);
                            lastValue = ByteToStr(lastArr[1]) + ByteToStr(lastArr[0]);
                        }

                        string hexString = BinaryStringToHexString(firstValue + lastValue);
                        uint num = uint.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

                        value = num.toDouble();

                    }

                    else if (register.VariableID == 11 || register.VariableID == 12)
                    {
                        byte[] firstArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value.toInt32());
                        var firstValue = string.Empty;
                        var lastValue = string.Empty;

                        if (register.VariableID == 12)
                        {
                            var value2 = plcData[tagValue.Index + 1].toInt32();
                            byte[] lastArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value2);

                            firstValue = ByteToStr(lastArr[1]) + ByteToStr(lastArr[0]);
                            lastValue = ByteToStr(firstArr[1]) + ByteToStr(firstArr[0]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var value2 = plcData[tagValue.Index - 1].toInt32();
                            byte[] lastArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value2);

                            firstValue = ByteToStr(firstArr[1]) + ByteToStr(firstArr[0]);
                            lastValue = ByteToStr(lastArr[1]) + ByteToStr(lastArr[0]);
                        }

                        string hexString = BinaryStringToHexString(firstValue + lastValue);
                        uint num = uint.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

                        byte[] floatVals = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
                        float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatVals, 0);

                        value = f.toDouble();
                    }//FLOAT


                    if (register.OffsetNP == "+")
                    {
                        value = Convert.ToDouble((value * register.Multiplier) + register.OffsetVal).toDouble();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = Convert.ToDouble((value * register.Multiplier) - register.OffsetVal).toDouble();
                    }


                    bool IsAdded = _manager.LiveValues.Any(x => x.TemplateValueID == register.ID && x.DeviceID == deviceID && x.TemplateID == templateID);

                    if (!IsAdded)
                    {
                        _manager.LiveValues.Insert(new tbl_LiveValues { CreateDate = DateTime.Now, DeviceID = deviceID, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, TemplateID = register.TagTemplateID, TemplateValueID = register.ID, Value = value.toDouble().ToString("F") });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tbl_LiveValues tbl_Live = _manager.LiveValues.Find(x => x.TemplateValueID == register.ID && x.DeviceID == deviceID && x.TemplateID == templateID);
                        tbl_Live.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        tbl_Live.Value = value.toDouble().ToString("F");
                        _manager.LiveValues.Update(tbl_Live);
                    }

                    //Add Archive
                    bool findArchiveTag = templateArchives.Any(x => x.TagValueID == register.ID && x.DeviceID == deviceID);

                    if (registerList[loopr].IsArchive)
                    {
                        TagTemplateArchive tagTemplateRegister = new TagTemplateArchive();

                        if (!findArchiveTag)
                        {
                            TagTemplateArchive archiveTag = new TagTemplateArchive();
                            archiveTag.TagValueID = register.ID;
                            archiveTag.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                            archiveTag.DeviceID = deviceID;
                            templateArchives.Add(archiveTag);
                            tagTemplateRegister = templateArchives.Find(x => x.TagValueID == register.ID && x.DeviceID == deviceID);

                            tbl_ArchiveValues ArchiveData = new tbl_ArchiveValues();
                            ArchiveData.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                            ArchiveData.DeviceID = deviceID;
                            ArchiveData.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                            ArchiveData.TemplateID = templateID;
                            ArchiveData.TemplateValueID = register.ID;
                            ArchiveData.Value = value.toDouble().ToString("F");
                            _manager.ArchiveValues.Insert(ArchiveData);
                            tagTemplateRegister.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                        tagTemplateRegister = templateArchives.Find(x => x.TagValueID == register.ID && x.DeviceID == deviceID);
                        TimeSpan tsArchive = DateTime.Now - tagTemplateRegister.LastModified;
                        double totalArchiveSeconds = tsArchive.TotalSeconds;
                        double tagArchiveSeconds = registerList[loopr].ArchiveP.TotalSeconds;

                        if (totalArchiveSeconds > tagArchiveSeconds)
                        {
                            tbl_ArchiveValues ArchiveData = new tbl_ArchiveValues();
                            ArchiveData.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                            ArchiveData.DeviceID = deviceID;
                            ArchiveData.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                            ArchiveData.TemplateID = templateID;
                            ArchiveData.TemplateValueID = register.ID;
                            ArchiveData.Value = value.toDouble().ToString("F");
                            _manager.ArchiveValues.Insert(ArchiveData);
                            tagTemplateRegister.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (findArchiveTag)
                        {
                            TagTemplateArchive archiveTagIsDeleted = templateArchives.Find(x => x.TagValueID == register.ID);

                            templateArchives.Remove(archiveTagIsDeleted);
                        }
                    }

                    #region AlarmLogger

                    List<tbl_Alarms> tagAlarms = _manager.Alarms.Where(x => x.DeviceID == deviceID && x.TagTemplateValueID == register.ID && x.IsDeleted == false && x.IsActive);
                    var alarmLogs = _manager.AlarmLogs.GetList();

                    foreach (var alarm in tagAlarms)
                    {

                        double LiveValue = value.ToString().Replace('.', ',').toDouble();
                        double AlarmValue = alarm.Value.Replace('.', ',').toDouble();
                        double AlarmValue2 = -9999;
                        if (alarm.Value2 != null && alarm.Value2.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            AlarmValue2 = alarm.Value2.Replace('.', ',').toDouble();
                        }

                        if (alarm.Operator == ">" && LiveValue > AlarmValue)
                        {

                            AlarmOn(_manager, alarm, LiveValue, alarmLogs, tagAlarms);
                        }
                        else if (alarm.Operator == ">=" && LiveValue >= AlarmValue)
                        {
                            AlarmOn(_manager, alarm, LiveValue, alarmLogs, tagAlarms);
                        }
                        else if (alarm.Operator == "<" && LiveValue < AlarmValue)
                        {
                            AlarmOn(_manager, alarm, LiveValue, alarmLogs, tagAlarms);
                        }
                        else if (alarm.Operator == "<=" && LiveValue <= AlarmValue)
                        {
                            AlarmOn(_manager, alarm, LiveValue, alarmLogs, tagAlarms);
                        }
                        else if (alarm.Operator == "=" && LiveValue == AlarmValue)
                        {
                            AlarmOn(_manager, alarm, LiveValue, alarmLogs, tagAlarms);
                        }
                        else if (alarm.Operator == "<=>=" && LiveValue >= AlarmValue && LiveValue <= AlarmValue2)
                        {
                            AlarmOn(_manager, alarm, LiveValue, alarmLogs, tagAlarms);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (alarmLogs.Any(x => x.AlarmID == alarm.ID))
                            {
                                if (alarmLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList().Find(x => x.AlarmID == alarm.ID).Status)
                                {
                                    int LastLogID = alarmLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList().Find(x => x.AlarmID == alarm.ID).ID;
                                    _manager.AlarmLogs.Insert(new tbl_AlarmLogs
                                    {
                                        AlarmDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                                        AlarmID = alarm.ID,
                                        Value = LiveValue,
                                        Status = false,
                                        BeforeLogID = LastLogID.ToString(),
                                        StatusText = "Çözüldü"
                                    });
                                    var UpdatingLog = alarmLogs.Find(x => x.ID == LastLogID);
                                    UpdatingLog.BeforeLogID = "-";
                                    _manager.AlarmLogs.Update(UpdatingLog);

                                    tbl_Alarms alarmVal = tagAlarms.Find(x => x.ID == alarm.ID);
                                    alarmVal.IsMail = false;
                                    alarmVal.IsSms = false;
                                    _manager.Alarms.Update(alarmVal);
                                }
                                else // Alarm Log tablosunda problem oluşursa düzelt
                                {
                                    var problemLogs = _manager.AlarmLogs.Where(x => x.AlarmID == alarm.ID && x.BeforeLogID == null);
                                    foreach (var pitem in problemLogs)
                                    {
                                        pitem.BeforeLogID = "-";
                                        _manager.AlarmLogs.Update(pitem);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    #region EventLogger

                    List<tbl_Events> events = _manager.Events.Where(x => x.DeviceID == deviceID && x.TagTemplateValueID == register.ID);
                    var eventLogs = _manager.EventLogs.GetList();
                    foreach (var _event in events)
                    {
                        double LiveValue = value.ToString().Replace('.', ',').toDouble();
                        double EventValue = _event.Value.Replace('.', ',').toDouble();
                        double EventValue2 = -9999;

                        if (_event.Value2 != null && _event.Value2.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            EventValue2 = _event.Value2.Replace('.', ',').toDouble();
                        }

                        if (_event.Operator == ">" && LiveValue > EventValue)
                        {
                            EventOn(_manager, _event, LiveValue, eventLogs, events);
                        }
                        else if (_event.Operator == ">=" && LiveValue >= EventValue)
                        {
                            EventOn(_manager, _event, LiveValue, eventLogs, events);
                        }
                        else if (_event.Operator == "<" && LiveValue < EventValue)
                        {
                            EventOn(_manager, _event, LiveValue, eventLogs, events);
                        }
                        else if (_event.Operator == "<=" && LiveValue <= EventValue)
                        {
                            EventOn(_manager, _event, LiveValue, eventLogs, events);
                        }
                        else if (_event.Operator == "=" && LiveValue == EventValue)
                        {
                            EventOn(_manager, _event, LiveValue, eventLogs, events);
                        }
                        else if (_event.Operator == "<=>=" && LiveValue >= EventValue && LiveValue <= EventValue2)
                        {
                            EventOn(_manager, _event, LiveValue, eventLogs, events);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (eventLogs.Any(x => x.EventID == _event.ID))
                            {
                                if (eventLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList().Find(x => x.EventID == _event.ID).Status)
                                {
                                    _manager.EventLogs.Insert(new tbl_EventLogs
                                    {
                                        EventID = _event.ID,
                                        LogTime = DateTime.Now,
                                        Status = false,
                                        Value = LiveValue
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            _manager.LiveValues.Save();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AsyncRead Method exception!!!!!! " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The problems are so frustrated in my algorithm. I cant create a synchronized thread when ı use ParalelFor and only I can reach data from the 4-5 device in 20 devices. If ı try to read them the normal way, the CPU usage gets too many. Another problem is, when ı create a thread first time, it takes 10 minutes to reread data from that device. I don't want to this happen. I want to read all the data from all devices transiently.

Comment: that is a lot of code to expect people to read through

Comment: You're right, but I haven't solved a problem in a week and I had to write down here as a last resort.

Comment: In terms  of increasing the chances of getting an answer here you need to take time to remove whatever lines of code aren't necessary. Not many people will voluntarily read through 500 lines of code on SO. On a more general note, having a method with 400 lines of code is a nightmare to maintain and near unreadable. if your methods do only one thing its a lot easier to read through and make changes to.  I strongly advise taking the time to properly structure your code, it will make it a lot easier for you and your team in the long run